# mv command is moving to the parent of the provided argument

Tags: command-line, directory, solaris, mv

Let's say I have a working directory:

```
/home/userID/workingDirectory
```

I type a `mv` command that will affect the parent directory of the current working directory and the working directory itself:

```
mv .* /tmp/someDirectory
```

When executed, the command moves the content of both directories `/home/userID` and `/home/userID/workingDirectory` because `.*` is a match of the `..` link in the current directory.

So far so good.

But, what I don't understand is why the files and directories are moved to the parent of the argument?

The files appear inside `/tmp` instead of `/tmp/someDirectory`

Can anybody throw some light?

OS is Solaris.

Thanks

Comment: Don't have solaris at hand so cannot verify, but you create all structure at the destination, so in particular move content of the parent directory `../*` to `/tmp/someDirectory/../*` which is `/tmp/*`.

Comment: Ah, so. When `mv` goes to the destination path; it's using the argument to recreate the directory structure. And, as the argument to recreate the structure has itself a `../*` then it's being interpreted as: `/tmp/someDirectory/../*` which will point to `/tmp` because is using the `..` link inside `/tmp/someDirectory`. Am I correct?

Comment: I'm not sure about that interpretation. Can you verify the expansion of the glob with something like `echo .* /tmp/someDirectory`?

Comment: I have access to the servers until monday haha... Posted the question here at home because it was bothering me all the way here.

Answer (score 3):

Because basically the system is doing the following when using `.*`.

`renameat(AT_FDCWD, "../workingDirectory", AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/narf/../workingDirectory") Err#18 EXDEV`
 
Thus it's moved to /tmp/workingDirectory instead of /tmp/narf

Comment: To be precise, given that the target is `/tmp`, the `mv` command probably first *attempts* your posted `renameat()` system call, which likely fails with `errno` set to `EXDEV` since `/tmp` is almost certainly on a different file system.  The `mv` command will then *copy* the file(s), and if successful delete the original(s).

Comment: Obviously. Otherwise it wouldn't throw the EXDEV. But it shows the directory string with the ".."